# Constants vs instance variable

Tags: ruby

When would you use a constant as opposed to a class instance variable? They both have the same scope. Examples would help.

Comment: How does a constant relate to an instance/object? If multiple instances are created, how many [of the same-named] constants exist? Answer the previous questions, but for instance variables. What happens when a constant is re-assigned, and why might re-assignment of a [*constant*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/constant) be discouraged?

Comment: I understand that unlike instance variables, constants *shouldn't* get reassigned across different instances. What I'm trying to understand is when would a person use constants vs instance variables, if in Ruby you can easily reassign a constant?

Comment: Good. Continue to answer the first two questions, for constants and then instance variables - that should be the key in completing the puzzle. Consider an attribute about an object - eg. `@name` of a person - and an name for a well-known value - eg. 3.14etc for `PI`. The well-known (constant) value doesn't change, and is independent of any instances. The @name variable is unique per person (or instance of a Person class).

Comment: Some examples would help my understanding of "good" constant usage vs instance variable usage vs class variable usage, since as a noob to Ruby, I'm having a hard time thinking through examples to answer your first two questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider this class:

```
class Dog
  NUMBER_OF_LEGS = 4

  @dog_counter = 0

  attr_reader :name


  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end


  def legs
    NUMBER_OF_LEGS
  end
end
```

Here, `NUMBER_OF_LEGS` is a *constant*, `@name` is an *instance variable* (with a getter method), and `@dog_counter` is what's called a *class instance variable*.

In Ruby everything is an object, even classes, and as such they can have their own instance variables.

Look at how we could use this class:

```
dog = Dog.new('Chewbacca')
dog.name
# => 'Chewbacca'

dog.legs
# => 4
Dog::NUMBER_OF_LEGS
# => 4
```

That's fine, but we **do not** have a direct interface to access `@dog_counter`. The only way to do something with it is to use introspection methods:

```
dog.class.instance_variable_get(:@dog_counter)
# => 0
dog.class.instance_variable_set(:@dog_counter, 1)

dog.class.instance_variable_get(:@dog_counter)
# => 1

dog.class.instance_eval { @dog_counter = 10 }
dog.class.instance_variable_get(:@dog_counter)
# => 10
```

We can do better than that. Look at this other implementation:

```
class Dog
  @dog_counter = 0

  attr_reader :name

  class << self
    attr_accessor :dog_counter
  end

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
    self.class.dog_counter += 1
  end

end
```

Now we have defined a class accessor (setter and getter), and we're also incrementing it with each new instance. The interface is simple:

```
Dog.dog_counter
# => 0

dog_1 = Dog.new('Han')
dog_2 = Dog.new('Luke')


Dog.dog_counter
# => 2
dog_2.class.dog_counter
# => 2
```

As to proper *class variables*, they are scoped on the class and can be accessed by instances.

The big problem, however, is that they are shared between all classes in the same hierarchy. Each class that sets a new value will update it for all its ancestors and descendants.

For this reason they are generally avoided, and *class instance variables* are preferred (they are class specific).

```
class Scientist
  @@greet = "Hello, I'm a Scientist!"

  def greet
    @@greet
  end
end


class Biologist < Scientist
  @@greet = "Hello, I'm a Biologist!"
end


class Physicist < Scientist
  @@greet = "Hello, I'm a Physicist!"
end


class ParticlePhysicist < Physicist
 @@greet = "Hello, I'm a ParticlePhysicist!"
end



biologist = Biologist.new
biologist.greet
# => "Hello, I'm a ParticlePhysicist!"
```

Answer (score 2):

They don't have the same scope. A class and its instances refer to the same constant, but not to the same instance variable, given the same name. Constants can also be referred from the namespace of a module, but instance variables cannot.

When you want to access something that would be referred to both from a class method and an instance method, or from some other module, then you need a constant.

You can go against the warnings, but that is not good. When you have something that changes, it is better to use a variable.

Comment: I noted that global variables didn't make your short list.

Answer (score 0):

About a constant and an instance variable having the same scope:

```
C = 10

class Dog
  def initialize
    puts C    #=>10
    @x = 1
    puts @x   #=>1
  end
end

d = Dog.new
puts C       #=>10
p @x         #=>nil  It sure doesn't look like @x has the same scope as C.
```

...

```
@x = 1

class Dog
  C = 10

  def initialize
    puts C    #=>10
    p @x      #=>nil  Here @x does not have the same scope as C.
  end
end

d = Dog.new
puts @x      #=>1
puts C       #=>Error uninitialized constant.  Here C does not have the same scope as @x.
```

Now for some jargon:

1. An instance variable attaches itself to whatever object is self at the time the instance variable is created.
2. An instance variable is looked up in whatever object is self at the time the instance variables is summoned.

Inside initialize(), a Dog instance is self.  At the toplevel, self is an Object called 'main'.  That should allow you to figure out the results above.

@variables attach themselves to instances, while methods attach themselves to a Class.  Instances of the same class share the methods in the class, but instances of a class do not share @variables--each instance has its own @variables; two instances don't even have to have the same @variables:

```
class Dog
  attr_accessor :x, :y, :z
  def initialize
  end
end

d1 = Dog.new
d1.x = 10

d2 = Dog.new
d2.y = 1
d2.z = 2


p d1.instance_variables
p d2.instance_variables

--output:--
[:@x]
[:@y, :@z]
```

*Local variables*, e.g. 'x', 'y', are for storing values that can change.

*Constants* are for storing values that you don't want to change.

*@variables* are for attaching values to an instance.  If you want an @variable to be constant, then don't define a setter method, although that is not foolproof because ruby permits a programmer to violate privacy if they wish.